# cannot ping [/my_turtle]: unknown node

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

working the tutorials, all went well until

[code]
rosnode ping my_turtle
[/code]

got back

[code]
rosnode: node is [/my_turtle]
cannot ping [/my_turtle]: unknown node
[/code]

Verified path, network setup, etc all went exactly as described until ping.  First time working with ROS, what should I look at next?

edit:
went back through tutorial, but before changing name of turtlesim to my_turtle, pinged turtlesim and it worked fine.

regards, Richard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37456/cannot-ping-%5B/my_turtle%5D:-unknown-node/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Judging from your edit I'm guessing you are pinging the wrong name. View the running nodes with `rosnode list`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1